# Labels disappear after they're clicked in Blogger

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the labels list on my blog (http://phobosmoon.blogspot.co.uk). I've tweaked it a little to make it look good, but I can't figure out how to change how it looks once it's been clicked. At the moment, if you click on any of the labels (book review, picture, etc), that label goes totally transparent, the text jumps up and changes colour, the border and box disappears and it just looks really strange. Where in the CSS/HTML can I change this? I've been teaching myself code so I need step by step instructions!

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 0):

You applied css on `.tabs-inner .widget li a`, but you replace the `a` element by a `span` when you are on the corresponding page. You should add an `active` class to the `li` element that does not have a link. Then add this to your css :

```
.tabs-inner .widget li a, .tabs-inner .widget li.active {
    /* your code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your CSS styling is being applied to the < A > tag.

Make sure you created a selected tab style for ".tabs-inner .widget li span" (It appears the link tag is replaced with a span.)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS styles are being done to the anchor tag links

```
.tabs-inner .widget li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin-right: .25em;
  color: #151537;
  font: normal normal 16px Georgia, Utopia, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, serif;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -goog-ms-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background: transparent url(//www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/white80.png) repeat scroll top left;
  border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
```

When you go to the specific page, the previous anchor link gets changed to a `span`
So therefore, you need to add it to the styling

```
.tabs-inner .widget li a, .tabs-inner .widget li span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin-right: .25em;
  color: #151537;
  font: normal normal 16px Georgia, Utopia, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, serif;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -goog-ms-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background: transparent url(//www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/white80.png) repeat scroll top left;
  border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
```

**Note**: Using Brewal's method is the correct way to handle this situation. That way you can always apply different styling to the currently `active` one.

Comment: In that particular case, both of those methods seems to fit. With yours however, we don't have to change the html.

Comment: @Brewal Yes, correct. But since the OP mentioned he was learning, I thought he should know that using a class "flag" is the way to go. Classes are cool.